# React Native Webview Library is not working in my app

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm just trying to make a ReactNative app that will display a simple webpage. But all I can see is a blank screen in my browser (Google) and my Expo Go says Network response timed out. Could somebody help me out, please?

#### I have given my code below:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,  } from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {

  const GOOGLE = "https://www.google.com/"

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
      <WebView
        source = {{uri : GOOGLE}}
      />
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

[Blank screen image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyZi0.png)

> I have done `npm install react-native-webview`

Answer (score 0):

you cant npm install react-native-webview because it has native dependencies.

You need to install it through expo by going

expo install react-native-webview

you can read this for more

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webview/

Comment: Hi, I'm really grateful for your answer! I have been posting questions on stackoverflow.com but you are the first person who has responded. Thank you very much.

Comment: no problem!  if it helps please accept the answer as well :)

Comment: Hi, the output is the same as before. Could you please help me out? I have used `expo install react-native-webview`

Comment: try removing your version of webview and then following the URL i linked, the documentation there is better than anything i can give